# Robocopy /purge only without archive attribute

Tags: sync, robocopy, purge

i am working on a robocopy command to sync different folders.

But for some reasons i just want to delete with purge the files without an archive attribute. Is this possible?

/Purge /E /NOCOPY /Log:%Logfile02% /TS /X /V /TEE  /w:3 /r:10 /XA:A

So the combination of /Purge /E /nocopy and /XA:A  is not working. /IA:A also not working. Anyone have another idea?